Lettrine and polyglossia error
Until recently, I have had no problem with the MWE included here. But after an uneventful installation of texlive 2024 on Ubuntu (Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS) the other day, I found that there was a problem.
If I uncomment \setotherlanguage{arabic} and try to run the xelatex engine, the output says:
! Package xkeyval Error: `loversize' undefined in families `L'.

See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

? 

If then, I remove the option loversize, it complains:
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LettrineFont \L@initial 

Instead, when I disable \setotherlanguage{arabic}, it runs as desired.
While trying to figure this out, I loaded a previous version of lettrine.sty ([2020-03-14 v2.23 (Daniel Flipo)]), the one used successfully prior to this whole mess --- and all was well again.
Is it a problem with lettrine? or polyglossia? maybe bidi? or something else?
A previous post from a few years ago seems to be similar to this.
xelatex: lettrine breaks in the presence of polyglossia
I'm grateful for your help.
fr. mgc
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{latin}

%\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\begin{document}
\lettrine[loversize=.4]{H}{oc est} ad experimentum. \lipsum[12]


\end{document}


I believe the culprit is bidi.

See https://github.com/kvafa/bidi/issues/31

The bidi Arabic setup patches lettrine but does not account for more recent versions. See
https://github.com/kvafa/bidi/issues/31
The simplest workaround is to tell lettrine to use an older version. this works without error.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lettrine}[=v2.3]
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{latin}

\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\begin{document}

\lettrine[loversize=.4]{H}{oc est} ad experimentum. \lipsum[12]


\end{document}


This is reported in here, so I'm not sure what should we do about it on the polyglossia side. The problem will happen with babel and the bidi=bidi option. Using LuaLaTeX you won't get this error.

@UdiFogiel ah thanks I will adjust the wording

Version 2.60 of lettrine.sty and after (current is 2.61) have been made compatible with bidi. Rather than using older versions of lettrine.sty, I recommend to just remove the file lettrine-xetex-bidi.def which wrongly patches (an older version of) the internal command \@lettrine. bidi will then work fine with versions 2.60 or 2.61 of lettrine.sty.

A possibility is to create an empty lettrine-xetex-bidi.def file in the working directory.
